# Excel Formula with conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

This feels like it should be simple but my head is hurting now and I'm struggling.

I need to add a condition to an existing sheet which already contains formulas and references to other sheets.

[image]

Also likely to want to add additional condition at a later time kind of like D2 =sheet2!a1 if C2 = Yes otherwise leave blank unless E2 = 100.

Comment: looks like a case for a nested IF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
 =IF(C2="NO",IF(E2=100,Sheet2!A1,""),Sheet2!A1)
```

**If C2="NO" then**:

- *If E2=100 then:*

  - Sheet2!A1
- *Else:*

  - "" (blank)

**Else:**

- Sheet2!A1